# Issue with PHPmailer and Google reCapcha V2 validation

Tags: php, validation, phpmailer, recaptcha

I'm having issues with Google reCapcha verification in a form using PHPmailer. When the form is completed and the check in "I'm not a robot" is ok, press SEND and this message appears:
"reCaptcha is not Valid! Please try again.".

I've tried with reloading, change navigator to latest version, delete historial, and nothing works.

This is the message in the Google reCapcha admin panel: "We have detected that your website does not verify reCAPTCHA solutions. These verifications are necessary for the service to function properly on your website. You can get more information on our developer website".

Furthermore, I've set the `allow_url_fopen = on` for testing, but still doesn't work.

Does anyone figure out what's going on, and what's the best solution?

**Actualization 13/06:**
The ERROR_LOG shows this:

```
[13-Jun-2021 21:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/mywebsite/public_html/include/contact-form.php on line 90
[13-Jun-2021 21:20:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=XX--very long code here--XX): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/mywebsite/public_html/include/contact-form.php on line 90
```

The contact-form.PHP file original is this:

```
<?php

session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
header('Content-type: application/json');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'php-mailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'php-mailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
//require 'php-mailer/src/SMTP.php';


// Enter your email address. If you need multiple email recipes simply add a comma: email@domain.com, email2@domain.com
$to = "";

// Add your reCaptcha Secret key if you wish to activate google reCaptcha security
$recaptcha_secret_key = ''; 

// Default message responses
const RESPONSE_MSG = [
    'success' => [
        "message_sent"           => "We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your message. We will get back to you as soon as possible."
    ],
    'form' => [
        "recipient_email"        => "Message not sent! The recipient email address is missing in the config file.",
        "name"                   => "Contact Form",
        "subject"                => "New Message From Contact Form"
    ],
    'google' => [
        "recapthca_invalid"     => "reCaptcha is not Valid! Please try again.",
        "recaptcha_secret_key"  => "Google reCaptcha secret key is missing in config file!"
    ]

];

//This functionality will process post fields without worrying to define them on your html template for your customzied form. 
//Note: autofields will process only post fields that starts with name widget-contact-form OR with custom prefix field name
$form_prefix = isset($_POST["form-prefix"]) ? $_POST["form-prefix"] : "widget-contact-form-";
$form_title = isset($_POST["form-name"]) ? $_POST["form-name"] : RESPONSE_MSG['form']['name'];
$subject = isset($_POST[$form_prefix."subject"]) ? $_POST[$form_prefix."subject"] : RESPONSE_MSG['form']['subject'];
$email = isset($_POST[$form_prefix."email"]) ? $_POST[$form_prefix."email"] : null;
$name = isset($_POST[$form_prefix."name"]) ? $_POST[$form_prefix."name"] : null;


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    
    if($email != '') {
        if(empty($to)) {
            $response = array ('response'=>'warning', 'message'=> RESPONSE_MSG['form']['recipient_email']);
            echo json_encode($response);
            die;
        }
            
        //If you don't receive the email, enable and configure these parameters below: 
        //$mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));
        //$mail->IsSMTP();
        //$mail->Host = 'mail.yourserver.com';                  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers, example: smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com
        //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to  587 or 465
        //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        //$mail->Username = 'SMTP username';                    // SMTP username
        //$mail->Password = 'SMTP password';                    // SMTP password

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                    
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = $name;
        if(strpos($to, ',') !== false){
            $email_addresses = explode(',', $to);
            foreach($email_addresses as $email_address) {
                $mail->AddAddress(trim($email_address));
            }
        }
        else {$mail->AddAddress($to);}
        $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject; 


       // Check if google captch is present
       if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

            if(empty($recaptcha_secret_key)) {
                $response = array ('response'=>'error', 'message'=> RESPONSE_MSG['google']['recaptcha_secret_key']);
                echo json_encode($response);
                die;
            }
            $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$recaptcha_secret_key.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
            $response_data = json_decode($response);
            
            if ($response_data->success !== true ) {
                $response = array ('response'=>'error', 'message'=> RESPONSE_MSG['google']['recapthca_invalid']);
                echo json_encode($response);
                die;
            }
        }

        //Remove unused fields
        foreach (array("form-prefix", "subject", "g-recaptcha") as $fld) {
            unset($_POST[$form_prefix . $fld]);
        }
        unset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        //Format eMail Template 
        $mail_template  = '<table width="100%" cellspacing="40" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><tbody><tr><td>';
        $mail_template .= '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#475159;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:70%"><tbody>';
        $mail_template .= '<tr><td style="padding-top:20px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;width:100%;text-align:right; font-size:12px;line-height:22px">This email is sent from&nbsp;'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'</td></tr>';
        $mail_template .= '</tbody></table>';
        $mail_template .= '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" style="padding: 50px; border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#475159;margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:70%; background-color:#ffffff;"><tbody>';
        $mail_template .= '<tr><td style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:36px;line-height:42px">'.$form_title.'</td></tr>';
        $mail_template .= '<tr><td style="padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:40px; font-size:16px;">';
        foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
                $split_field_name = str_replace($form_prefix, '', $field);
                $ucwords_field_name = ucfirst(str_replace('-', ' ', $split_field_name));        
                $mail_template .= '<p style="display:block;margin-bottom:10px;"><strong>'.$ucwords_field_name.': </strong>'.$value.'</p>';
        }  
        $mail_template .= '</td></tr>';
        $mail_template .= '<tr><td style="padding-top:16px;font-size:12px;line-height:24px;color:#767676; border-top:1px solid #f5f7f8;">Date: '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").'</td></tr>';
        $mail_template .= '<tr><td style="font-size:12px;line-height:24px;color:#767676">From: '.$email.'</td></tr>';
        $mail_template .= '</tbody></table>';
        $mail_template .= '</td></tr></tbody></table>';
        $mail->Body = $mail_template; 

        // Check if any file is attached
        $attachments = [];
        if (!empty($_FILES[$form_prefix.'attachment'])) {
            $result = array();
            foreach ($_FILES[$form_prefix.'attachment'] as $key => $value) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
                    $result[$i][$key] = $value[$i];
                }
            }
            foreach ( $result as $key => $attachment) {
                 $mail->addAttachment($attachment['tmp_name'],$attachment['name']); 
            }
        }

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $response = array ('response'=>'error', 'message'=> $mail->ErrorInfo);  
        }else {                  
            $response = array ('response'=>'success', 'message'=> RESPONSE_MSG['success']['message_sent']);  
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response = array ('response'=>'error');     
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you,

Alejandra

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHPMailer. Disable all your other code and focus on just the things the recaptcha docs tell you to.

Comment: Your comment is not helpful. We all are here to learn, even who start from scratch. If you're unable to share knowledge, please let other people to do it. Thank you! 

Comment: I was pointing out that you are trying to fix a problem via a *very* indirect route. It's like saying your car won't start because you've lost your keys; it's nothing to do with the car! Trying to fix multiple issues at once is a recipe for confusion, as you're finding. The first step in debugging is to cut back your code to the minimum to reproduce the problem. Does recaptcha have anything to do with sending email? No, so eliminate that (temporarily) from your code so you can concentrate on the bits that are not working. You also need to post your code or we have no hope of helping you.

Comment: First step is done. The email is working fine without recapcha but I need recapcha work with it, because of the spam I am receiving.

Comment: Great, so now you know that the email part is working you can concentrate on getting recaptcha working.

Comment: Thank you, but you're still not helping. I've review code, tested in server, and can't find the problem. That's the reason I am here...